# insert array using insert many function of mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my Schema,

```js
var trainListSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    trainNo: Number,
    trainName:String,
    fromStation : String,
    toStation: String,
    runningDays: [{type:Number}],
    trainType: String,
    createdTime: {type:Date , default:Date.now}})
```

and this is the function used to insert multiple documents.

```js
  createTrainList: function(data) {
    trainList.insertMany(data, function(err, post) {
                            if (err) return next(err);
                            console.log(post);
                        });
  }
```

Now as you can se runningDays is an array. While using the above method to insert data. runningDays gets inserted as 0 elements while rest of the field gets inserted successfully.

How should I go about inserting array within array using mongoose.
Help will be appreciated.

Here is the sample JSON.

```html
[
  {
    "trainNo": "10104",
    "trainName": "MANDOVI EXPRESS",
    "fromStation": "MAO",
    "toStation": "CSTM",
    "days": [
      0,
      1,
      2,
      3,
      4,
      5,
      6
    ],
    "trainType": "MAIL EXP"
  },
  {
    "trainNo": "10111",
    "trainName": "KONKAN KANYA EX",
    "fromStation": "CSTM",
    "toStation": "MAO",
    "days": [
      0,
      1,
      2,
      3,
      4,
      5,
      6
    ],
    "trainType": "MAIL EXP"
  }]
```

Comment: what is the `json` document you're trying to insert.. can you post the document?

Comment: I have added json in the question

Comment: Yup! Your notated data says `"days"` but your "Schema" says `"runningDays"`. So the data is mismatched to the schema and is not added. Correct the data source to the expected field name, or vice versa.

Comment: Yeah that was a dumb mistake friom my end.. Thanks for your help. If you mention your comment as an answer I will accept it. Thanks